# How to configure SNI in nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, sni

I wish to serve two or more of my domain names from a single instance of nginx running on a raspberry pi, however something is not working alright.

Nginx was compiled with SNI support enabled:

```
> nginx -VC
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
TLS SNI support enabled
```

However I suspect that SNI is not in effect. I am trying to access my domains from multiple modern browsers guaranteed to have SNI support (firefoxes, chromes, opera and more).

My configurations are as follows:
`/etc/nginx/sites_enabled/domain1.conf` contains the following:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    root /var/www/domain1.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    ssl_certificate /var/www/domain1.com/ssl/cert.pub;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/domain1.com/ssl/cert.key;
    location / { try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404; }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

whereas `/etc/nginx/sites_enabled/domain2.conf` containsthe following:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain2.net www.domain2.net;
    root /var/www/domain2.net/html;
    index index.html;
    ssl_certificate /var/www/domain2.net/ssl/cert.pub;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/domain2.net/ssl/cert.key;
    location / { try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404; }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.net www.domain2.net;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

The HTTP to HTTPS redirecting works as expected i.e. in a browsers http://domain1.com correctly redirects me to https://domain1.com, however only one of the domains are actually accessible (namely domain2.net).

What could be the cause of my problem?
Do I have to manually enable SNI somehow?

Note that when I set up both domains only through HTTP they both worked as expected.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that the `server` block is present with an exact match in the `server_name` directive. Also, clear your browser's cache between changes to the Nginx configuration. It might be helpful to use `curl` rather than a browser to test your website.

Comment: *"however only one of the domains are actually accessible (namely domain2.net)"* - and what happens for the other? Please provide the actual and exact error messages and/or error behavior you get. Depending on what you see it might be improperly setup DNS, wrong certificate, wrong certificate chain, wrong URL used ...

Comment: thank you for the suggestion of using curl, it removes the necessity of repeatedly clearing browser cache..., upon using the -T flag I verified that both server blocks are present in the entire config.
Using curl I have found that domain1.com is seemingly being redirected, much like the http requests are redirected to https counterparts, in a browser I am prsented with a page stating that "The page isn't redirected properly".

Comment: About the DNS, I have purchased both domains via cloudflare and created an "origin certificate" for both.